# Delphi XE 5 - App not visible if Logitech Commander open

Tags: delphi

Clients are reporting that my app compiled using Delphi XE5 is not visible if Logitech Commander is on their machine. My app is actually running, as it appears in the Task Bar and my shutdown dialog box appears when the user activates his ShutDown of his computer. I have no method to debug this as I do not have Logitech service available.  In the distant past, I have had other programs interfere, but they are usually free program rather than a commercial app.  Has anyone had this reported and, if so, any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Try and do some debugging to work out what it is about your app that makes this happen.

Comment: @David: ...with no way to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Mason The clients can reproduce it. If the programmer cannot, but the clients can, then some form of remote debugging is required.

Comment: @Mason: Yes, by either getting the clients to assist or by setting up a test machine (eg., a VM) and installing what you need to reproduce it. There's absolutely no information here we can use to try and help - no information about what might be in the Windows event log, no exception message, no logging output the poster has added that might indicate where it's failing, or anything else. (There's not even basic information about the *type* of application it is or what it does.)

Comment: Just to give us a hint: what exactly does your app do? Does it do something similar to Logitech's Alert Commander?

Comment: You don't need to have the service. You can try it free.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough reputation to add a comment so I'll try to answer:
Run the Commander while it's still running ¿It doesn't run a second instance of it? That's because when Commander runs it probably scans all active windows by name and shouts down, hides or disables those that match a specific form name.
I've found this to be a common practice.

Create a new test application with one empty form. The main form of this test app should have the same name as your app main form. Ask one of your clients to run it and if it has the same issue then we know, you will have to rename the main form of your application and re-deploy.
This happened to me once and since I haven't named any of my forms 'MainFrm', 'frmMain' 'TForm1', etc.

Comment: The OP did mention that his application does run (it does apear in the taskbar) the only problem is that applications window is not visible.